# Applying integral test to prove

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

$f$ is positive, continuous and decreasing on $[N,\infty)$. It is known that:

$$\int\limits_N^\infty f(x) \, dx< \infty \,, \text{ then }, \  \sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n \text{ is convergent}$$

Prove that,

$$ \text{If } \ p > 1, \text{ then }, \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n(\ln n)^p} \text{ is convergent}$$

I am a bit lost on where to start for this question. Pointing me to the right direction is sufficient as I have other questions to solve and it will help me in solving them :)

All help and suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Substitute $u=\ln x$ in the relevant integral.

Comment: Is the first statement written correctly?

Comment: @DavidMitra Actually, i am fine with the integration, but the p is throwing me off. I am not sure on how to handle it in the integration

Comment: If you type ln\ n you will see $ln\ n$, but if you type \ln n you will see $\ln n$.  That is standard usage.  I changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $f(x) = \frac{1}{x(\log(x))^p}$ and see the integration 
$$\int_N^{\infty} \frac{1}{x(\log(x))^p} = \lim_{M \rightarrow \infty} \int_N^{M} \frac{1}{x(\log(x))^p} = \lim_{M \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(\log(M))^{1-p}}{1 - p} - \frac{(\log(N))^{1-p}}{1 - p}$$
which is a finite quantity as $p > 1$. To find the integration just replace $\log(x)$ by $t$.

Now construct the series ans see convergence.